# HTML/JS/PHP: Transformar a entrada de data em dd/mm/aaaa

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, data

Bom dia. No meu banco de dados mysql as datas são salvas como dd/mm/aaaa, porém o input "date" do html retorna apenas datas no formato aaaa-mm-dd, de forma que não consigo filtrar as datas do banco de dados, que era meu objetivo. 
Estava usando um código bem simples, como este abaixo:

```
<input type="date"  name="parametro"> 
<input type="submit" value="Filtrar Data">
```

Como fazer para retornar a data no mesmo formato do banco? No caso de uso de plugins, como usá-los?

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada no **Moment.js** que faz exatamente isso: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Tu vai comparar as datas na query, certo? Se for possível, aconselho a armazenar as datas no formato Y-m-d para facilitar essa comparação

Comment: Você está trabalhando com um banco que já possuí datas formatadas ou está inserindo estas datas pela entrada do front-end? Pergunto isto para seus valores já armazenados ou que serão armazenados

Comment: O banco já possui datas formatas em dd/mm/aaaa. Uso o html para filtrar os dados do banco correspondentes à data inserida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com base nas respostas que obtive consegui achar uma solução:
Como eu precisava filtrar pela data no formato dd/mm/aaaa, usei o seguinte código em html e php:

`HTML`:

```
<input  type="date" placeholder= "dd/mm/aaaa" name="parametro" > 
<input type="submit" value="Filtrar Data">
```

`PHP`:

```
 $parametro = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro");
 $data = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($parametro));
```

Answer (score 1):

Com `PHP` é simples resolver, apenas converta a sua base para o formato do input

```
$dataBanco = "06/04/2018";
$data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataBanco));
echo $data;
```

Comment: Obrigada! Com base nesse código consegui fazer dar certo.